# Is it possible conatinerise the nx library

Tags: nrwl-nx

I have a nx library which is used by many nx apps inside the monorepo. Let's say 5 apps using that library.if I made any change in the library. Currently we deploying all the 5 apps.is there an way to only deploy the library and all the apps can consume it automatically without deploying them.

Answer (score 0):

In NX, Apps can be seen as deployable artifacts, whilst libs are pieces of functionality that are consumed by Apps.

You could potentially convert your 1 library into an app to containerise it to be consumed by your other Apps at runtime which would mean that your Apps wouldn't need to be redeployed, but this would mean injecting your deployed .js files into your HTML files. If you were to take this approach your Apps and your deployed Lib-App would need to know nothing about each other as Apps shouldn't reference each other. **I don't recommend this option.**

Another option would be to create a publishable library and import this into your Apps from a private registry. However, this would still require deployments of all your Apps, but you would have the option of when you wanted to increment the version number of your published Lib. This is rather anti-nx, and **I don't recommend this option either.** Here is a link anyway: [Publishable and Buildable Nx Libraries](https://nx.dev/more-concepts/buildable-and-publishable-libraries)

However, I think this question is more likely the result of lengthy deployment times and frequent changes to your Libs. If so, I would consider these points.

- Changing a Lib that is used by many Apps, also changes those Apps, hence those changes **should** be tested and deployed.
- If an App is not changed by a change in the Lib it is consuming, why is it consuming it? Could that Lib be broken down into smaller Libs to reduce dependencies?
- Could you create a collection of Libs that are specific for each App? An example layout could be:

```
/nx
-/apps
--/app1*
--/app2*
-/libs
--/apps
---/app1
----/pages
-----/page1*
----/ui
-----/component1*
----/services
-----/service1*
---/app2
----/pages
-----/page1*
----/ui
-----/component1*
----/services
-----/service1*
--/ui
---/component1*
--/services
---/service1*

// Where each starred line is a separate library. By doing this you will reduce the number of applications your change will affect, and as a result there will be fewer deployments.
```

- If you need to make a change to a library that is used by many apps, and you don't want to deploy them all out at the same time, consider creating a new library and referencing that new library in the App as you want to deploy it.
- Try not to include any code in an App that you could include in a Lib. It will reduce testing burden as only the Libs that have been affected by a change will need to be tested.